# renaming each file in a folder with a separate thread using python

Tags: python, multithreading, operating-system, python-multithreading

I am trying to learn threading in python.

so far this is a simple piece of cake I wrote:

```
path = "/Users/userName/Desktop/temp/bluetooth"
allImages = tuple(img for img in os.listdir(path) if img.endswith(".JPG"))

def renameFile(index, path, fileName, renameTo):
    print "%d. Renamed: %s to %s" % (index, fileName, renameTo)
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, fileName), os.path.join(path, renameTo))
    return

def threadedRename():
    for  ind, img in enumerate(allImages):
        t = threading.Thread(target=renameFile, args=(ind, path, img, "%s%s" % (ind, img)))
        t.start()
threadedRename()
```

Does the above code renames a file simultanuesly by doing it each thread ? Does it make sense and if it does, how can I check the difference between the rename time taken by code above and code below ?

```
# perform rename one by one
for ind, img in enumerate(allImages):
    print "Renaming: %s" % img
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, img), os.path.join(path, "%s%s" % (ind, img)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a programming exercise to learn threading, there's nothing wrong with this, but it is not a good practical use of threads. Those are things for the OS and storage hardware to optimize, and on a physical disk, you'd have to violate the laws of physics to literally do them at the same time.

The important thing about the timer code is the "#do operations" part.  You're going to need to make a list of the threads as you create them, then do something like this to get the actual time they run:

```
# start timer

# start all the threads
for t in renameThreads:
    t.start

# wait for all threads to finish
for t in renameThreads:
    t.join()

# now you can stop the timer
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think creating a thread for each file is worth it here. The rename operation is not very lengthy to justify the overhead of creating a thread per file. Maybe if you have numerous files it would be worth it to create a couple of threads and have them do the work in batches.

In order to clock you program use `time.clock()`:

```
fromTime = time.clock()
#do operations
toTime = time.clock()
print toTime - fromTime
```

Comment: maybe depends on file some too, other wise is the approach correct ?